# Repeated String Match

Tags: python, algorithm

I did Contest 52 of leetcode.com and I had trouble understanding the solution. The problem statement is:

> Given two strings A and B, find the minimum number of times A has to be >repeated such that B is a substring of it. If no such solution, return -1.
>
> For example, with A = "abcd" and B = "cdabcdab.
>
> Return 3, because by repeating A three times (“abcdabcdabcd”), B is a >substring of it; and B is not a substring of A repeated two times
> ("abcdabcd").

The solution is:

```
def repeatedStringMatch(self, A, B):
      """
      :type A: str
      :type B: str
      :rtype: int
      """
      times = int(math.ceil(float(len(B)) / len(A)))
      for i in range(2):
        if B in (A * (times + i)):
          return times + i
      return -1
```

The explanation from one of the collaborators was:

> A has to be repeated sufficient times such that it is at least as long as >B (or one more), hence we can conclude that the theoretical lower bound >for the answer would be length of B / length of A.
>
> Let x be the theoretical lower bound, which is ceil(len(B)/len(A)).
>
> The answer n can only be x or x + 1

I don't understand why n can only be x or x+1, can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

If `x+1 < n` and B is a substring of A repeated `n` times and you've embedded B in it then either you can chop off the last copy of A without hitting B (meaning that `n` is not minimal) or else the start of B in A is after the end of the first copy so you can chop off the first copy (and again `n` is not minimal).

Therefore if it fits at all, it must fit within `x+1` copies.  Based on length alone it can't fit within `< x` copies.  So the only possibilities left are `x` and `x+1` copies.  (And examples can be found where each is the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have two strings `m = "abcde"` and any 11 character string `"e_abcde_abcde"`, `n` to be searched. Since the 11 digits are to be matched, the minimum number of characters required is 11 which requires `((n/m)+1)=3` minimum sets for search due to integer rounding. Now the ending position depends on the beginning position and there are at most `length(m)` unique starting points in each set of `m` elements. So we can start at each of the positions till the first set is exhausted. The last try may go to `m_last = 4`, hence the last element of the matched string will go to `(n/m+2)` set. After the first set is exhausted, the above pattern is exhausted and there is no new searches. Hence we require `(n/m + 2) * length (m)` for full search.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question still, I would like to add my 2 cents here.
I think @btilly has provided enough clarity but a picture may help further.

[image]