# Repeated String Match Leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm

Given two strings A and B, find the minimum number of times A has to be repeated such that B is a substring of it. If no such solution, return -1.

For example, with A = "abcd" and B = "cdabcdab".

Return 3, because by repeating A three times (“abcdabcdabcd”), B is a substring of it; and B is not a substring of A repeated two times ("abcdabcd").

Note:
The length of A and B will be between 1 and 10000.

The solution has this explanation:

Now, suppose q is the least number for which len(B) <= len(A * q). We only need to check whether B is a substring of A * q or A * (q+1). If we try k < q, then B has larger length than A * q and therefore can't be a substring. When k = q+1, A * k is already big enough to try all positions for B; namely, A[i:i+len(B)] == B for i = 0, 1, ..., len(A) - 1.

I am not able to wrap my head around q+1 case.If q is the minimum number to have B as substring than why in the code we have to check q + 1 case.

Question someone posted long ago.
[Repeated String Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555461/repeated-string-match)

Comment: Your statement is not correct, `If q is the minimum number to have B as substring ...` that is wrong. `q` is just the minimum number, such that `len(B) <= len(A * q)`. For example, if `A = abcd`, and `B = cdab`, so `q = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Take your example: A = "abcd" and B = "cdabcdab". Then `len(B) = 8` and `len(A) = 4`. Hence, `q = 2`. But `A * 2 = abcdabcd`, so `B` is not a substring. Therefore, you need to check `A * 3 = abcdabcdabcd` as well.

Note that `q` is not the minimum number for `B` to be a substring of `A*q`, but the least number for which `len(B) <= len(A*q)` holds.

Comment: Then it could be q + 2 as well.

Comment: Sure, if B is a substring of `A*(q+1)` it is also a substring of `A*(q+n)`, but the question you gave asks for the "minimum number of times A has to be repeated", and that is either `q` or `q+1`, so checking these two is sufficient. If B is not a substring of `A*(q+1)`, it is never a substring.